# Производная линия делит 2 градиента css js

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: то что должно получиться]

Привет, это мой 2 макет не судите строго). есть линия от которой вверху и внизу градиенты. Не имею малейшего понятия как это можно реализовать. Первое обращение за помощью, критика приветствуется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: на svg делайте...

Comment: саму линию могу а как сделать так чтоб был под ней градиент?